# Vb.Net Error This OleDbTransaction has completed; it is no longer usable

Tags: vb.net, oracle10g, vb.net-2010

I have a VB.Net desktop application that does three tasks.  First, it inserts data into Table A, then Table B, and finally, it copies a file from one directory to another.  I am using transactions for my database inserts.  In the event that an error occurs in any of the three steps, I want to roll back the transaction.  The problem is, when a specific scenario occurs, and I roll back the transaction, i get the following error:

```
 This OleDbTransaction has completed; it is no longer usable.
```

This happens if both database inserts succeed but the file copy fails.  I'm not sure if I've set up my transactions wrong or what.  If anyone has any feedback, let me know.  Oh and the database I'm using is Oracle 10g.  Bellow is my code:

```
Private Sub insertNew(ByVal doc As someObject)
   Dim conString As String
   conString = "Provider=MSDAORA.1;" _
                  & "User ID=" & My.Settings.User & ";" _
                  & "Password=" & My.Settings.Password & ";" _
                  & "Data Source=" & My.Settings.DatabaseName & ";" _
                  & "Persist Security Info=False"

   Dim insertString1 As String
   Dim insertString2 As String
   Dim transaction As OleDbTransaction  


   insertString1 = "INSERT INTO mySchema.myTable1(ID_DOC, ID_DOC_FORMAT) VALUES (?,?)"
   insertString2 = "INSERT INTO mySchema.myTable2(LOCATION_ID, PK_DOCUMENT) VALUES (?,?)"

   Dim conn As New OleDbConnection(conString)

   Try
      Dim nextValue As Integer
      'this function is a database call to get next sequence from database
      nextValue = readData()

      Using conn
        conn.Open()
        transaction = conn.BeginTransaction()

        Dim command1 As New OleDbCommand
        Dim command2 As New OleDbCommand

        Try
            With command1
               .Connection = conn
               .Transaction = transaction
               .CommandType = CommandType.Text
               .CommandText = insertString1
               .Parameters.Add("@IdDoc", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = doc.IdDoc
               .Parameters.Add("@IdDocFormat", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = doc.IdDocFormat
               .ExecuteNonQuery()
            End With
        Catch exCMD1 As Exception
             Throw New ApplicationException("unable to insert into table DM_DOCUMENTS (" & exCMD1.Message & ")")
        End Try

       Try
          With command2
           .Connection = conn
           .Transaction = transaction
           .CommandType = CommandType.Text
           .CommandText = insertString2
           .Parameters.Add("@IndPyramid", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = doc.IndPyramid
           .Parameters.Add("@LocationId", OleDbType.Integer).Value = doc.LocationId
           .ExecuteNonQuery()
          End With

        Catch exCMD2 As Exception
            Throw New ApplicationException("unable to insert into table DM_LOCATION_DOC_XREF (" & exCMD2.Message & ")")
        End Try

        If copyFiles(doc.IdDoc) = True Then
            transaction.Commit()
            'everything was a success, so commit
        Else
           'error copying file, so roll back.  
           '  If the error originates from here, it will throw to the next catch, and that is where I get the described error     
           Throw New ApplicationException("unable to copy to New Path")
        End If
    End Using
Catch ex As Exception
     If transaction IsNot Nothing Then
       'error occurs here if it came from trying to copy files code block
       transaction.Rollback()
     End If
     Throw
        Finally
            conn.Close()
            conn.Dispose()
        End Try

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind.  It was because I was trying to rollback the transaction outside of the correct Try Catch statement.  After you exit the using statement, the db stuff gets disposed of and this will cause the error.  I just redid my try catch statements and now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you check whether the connection associated to that transaction is null or not then you are done.

Only apply commit or rollback if the connection object of the transaction is not null

eg.

OleDBTransaction testTransaction = someOleDBConnection.BeginTransaction();

//your all transactional codes

if(testTransaction.Connection != null)
    testTransaction.Rollback() OR testTransaction.Commit()  //Based on your requirement

Answer (score 0):

you can try the different Isolation Level of transaction.

```
transaction = conn.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted)
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.isolationlevel(v=vs.110).aspx